# asp.net not showing gridview in IE

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

Works fine in google chrome and firefox but GRIDVIEW is not appearing in IE11.
No errors in console, viewed source and it just isnt there??

Had a look online and couldnt find much someone suggested adding in GridLines="None" but that didnt have any effect....Any ideas please?

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%" ViewStateMode="Enabled"
                        BorderWidth="1px" BackColor="White" CellPadding="3" BorderStyle="None"
                        BorderColor="#CCCCCC" Font-Names="Arial" GridLines="None">



                        <FooterStyle ForeColor="#000066" BackColor="White"></FooterStyle>
                        <PagerStyle ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left"
                            BackColor="White"></PagerStyle>
                        <HeaderStyle ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True"
                            BackColor="#1e4964"></HeaderStyle>
                        <Columns>

                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="SelectedCheckBox" runat="server" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckHeader" OnCheckedChanged="CheckHeader_OnCheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" />
                                </HeaderTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="File" DataField="File">
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date Added" DataField="DateAdded" DataFormatString="{0:d}">
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                            </asp:BoundField>



                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <a href="<%# ResolveUrl((string)Eval("LargePictureURL"))%>" onclick="magnificPopup('GridView1')">
                                        <img alt="" src='<%# ResolveUrl((string)Eval("PictureURL"))%>' style="max-height: 20px; max-width: 30px; text-align: center" />
                                    </a>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="ID" Visible="true">
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                            </asp:BoundField>



                        </Columns>
                        <SelectedRowStyle ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True"
                            BackColor="#669999"></SelectedRowStyle>
                        <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066"></RowStyle>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

**UPDATE**
The gridview is populated with

```
// Update the images displayed on the gridview
        GridView1.DataSource = GetData(false);
        GridView1.DataBind();
        upViewUploadImages.Update();
```

Same process shows images for FIREFOX and GOOGLE but not on IE.

Comment: debug your code step by step to see why is not there....

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that **you don't have set the data source on your grid view** - `DataSourceID` not exist at all.

To display some data your on grid view you need to tell him what that data are.

So I will confuse at first because I believe the the IE11 was the problem but after your comments I realize that **you do not have set any data** to show !

Eg: You must have something like (if you do not use code behind data binder)

```
<asp:GridView   DataSourceID="ThisPageSql" runat="server" ...

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="ThisPageSql" runat="server"  
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DbCoonect %>" ...
```

Comment: @John You totally change the question... again debug your code step by step on code behind, and check if the browsers files on server is up to date and check what browser capabilities find for ie